# Improve Sound Quality Of USB Microphone

Tags: microphone, ableton-live, ableton, usb, microphone-technique

I’m pretty new to recording music, I’m using Ableton Live 10 Intro and an Audio Technica AT2020USB mic. I feel like I’m not really getting the best quality sound out of the mic and based on the reviews I’ve read I don’t think it’s the mic that’s the problem. I’m not really sure where to start, I only know how to adjust gain and reduce latency to improve performance and quality. I’m using Mac OS and the standard CoreAudio driver. Also, when I record I do it on the “1” channel, vs “1/2” or “2”, and use an audio track to record on.

Comment: The room that you're recording in is going to have a big affect on the quality of your recording, can you provide some detail of that?

Comment: It’s a pretty big room, oddly shaped. Like a square attached to a triangle. Pretty packed with furniture.

Comment: What's the difference between the sound you get and the sound you want to get? If you want a "professional" sound then you'll need to run it through a compressor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the mic in the right place, point it in the right direction, and feed it high quality audio.

For example, if you're recording voice (singing or speaking), then where you place the mic in front of the person talking or singing makes a *huge* difference in sound quality. If you put the mic closer to their chest, then their voice will start to sound more boomy. Closer to their nose, brighter and maybe more nasal. Closer and farther and left and right also make a big difference.

With musical instruments or other sound sources, placement is just as important and can be more complicated.

One thing you might try is moving the mic around slowly while making a test recording. Perhaps take some video at the same time. Listen back to the recording and when you find the part of the recording with the best sound, find that spot on the video and use the video as a guide to how to put the mic back in the best spot.